# How to send form data to a independent component which opens using window. Open

Tags: javascript, angular, angularjs

I have to send the form data( on button click) to a another component which don't have any relationship.

Now my requirement is i need to send this form data to another window where the component loads using window.open.

Now please tell me how can i use window.open to send this form data to another page ??

Thanks in advance .

Answer (score 0):

One way could be to use a shared service.

Component 1 sends form data to -> Service e.g via subscription.

On window.open Component 2 subscribes to -> Service to check if there is data.

https://enlear.academy/sharing-data-between-angular-components-f76fa680bf76